# Trouble getting rvm to install ruby-2.7.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rubygems, rvm

Working on a demo React-On-Rails project and I've been trying to get the backend working. I'm proficient in React, but Ruby/Rails is something I've never worked with.

I've installed everything, but when trying to install the gem file I' getting...

```
$ bundle install
Your Ruby version is 3.0.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.2
```

So, I've tried using rvm to install 2.7.2, but it just wont work.

```
App/server (master)
$ rvm install "ruby-2.7.2"
Required ruby-2.7.2 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.7.2"'
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: mingw/unknown/x86_64/ruby-2.7.2.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for mingw.
Requirements support for mingw is not implemented yet,
report a bug here => https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled bundle to get to this point. `$ gem install rails bundler`

This is what I have installed:

- rvm 1.29.12 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
- ruby 3.0.3p157 (2021-11-24 revision 3fb7d2cadc) [x64-mingw32]
- gem -v 3.2.33
- Bundler version 2.2.33

I'm running to App in VSC on Win11OS

How do I get rvm to run 2.7.2 so I can get bunder to install the Gemfile???

Comment: Any reason you can't use 3.0.3 since you have it installed already?

Comment: Gem file requires 2.7.2

Comment: So, you change the gemfile to 3.0.3 unless there is a reason to stay with 2.7.2.

Comment: Tried switching the required ruby version to 3.0.3 in the gemfile, but it just crashes with `An error occurred while installing pg (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.`

Comment: To compile postgres you need to have it installed locally. My recommendation: Use WSL so you can install those dependencies easier or go Docker.

Comment: Hey, @ChristopherOezbek I installed WSL with Ubuntu earlier, but I have no idea what to run. Do I just run rvm install "ruby-2.7.2" inside the root directory of the react/ruby app?

Comment: You need to install ruby-2.7.2 via rvm and then if you have your shell set-up correctly when you `cd` into the directory rvm will switch to 2.7.2.

Comment: Have you tried running `rvm install 2.7.2` (without the `ruby-` prefix)?

If this doesn't work, what does `rvm list known` returns?